# Woocommerce | Add character to order number based on login

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible when a registered user places an order that certain characters appear before the order number? Now I have found something that applies this to all orders. But it should only be on orders made from a user.

```
function filter_woocommerce_order_number( $order_number, $order ) {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                $prefix = 'B2B-';
        } else {
                $prefix = '';
        }
        
        return $prefix . $order_number;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'filter_woocommerce_order_number', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Use `wp_get_current_user` instead of `is_user_logged_in`. The returned `WP_User` instance will allow you to get the ID or other user details.

Comment: Ok thanks, but do i need to do anything with `woocommerce_new_order` ?

Comment: Depends on whether you want to manipulate the order number when you display it, or whether you actually want to write it into the database. (Not sure if WooCommerce would even accept such an order ID on the database level though, the column might be numeric.)